# Why my regexp not working properly? End line dont working in my expression

Tags: regex

**Why my regexp not working properly? End line dont working in my expression**

Exp: `/.+ \[(acion)(=|>|<|>=|<=|!=|=|!=)\]"[a-zA-Z ]*" |[a-zA-Z]+ |"[a-zA-Z ]*"$/gm`

result: `<sple> [acion>]a [acion=]a`

Look at the picture, there the first a is highlighted as valid, but I need the regular expression to see only the second a as valid. I think the problem is in the work of the end of the line, since I tell the expression to look only from the end and do not set the beginning

I will be glad of any help) Have a nice time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but some part of my exp defines by runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have `$` in the last alternative, so it's the only part that has to match at the end of the line. The other alternatives can match anywhere.

If you want `$` to apply to the whole expression, put a group around everything else.

```
/(?:.+ \[(acion)(=|>|<|>=|<=|!=|=|!=)\]"[a-zA-Z ]*" |[a-zA-Z]+ |"[a-zA-Z ]*")$/gm
```